# Carrierwave doesn't recreate versions after the model update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I've introduced a new version on my Carrierwave Uploader. When I create a new `Event` it creates both versions correctly. But when I update it, only the file I attached gets uploaded, but versions do not get recreated.

I am using `CarrierWave 1.2.2`, and looking at the changelog, it doesn't seem to have been a bug that got fixed in the newer versions

```rb
class CoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    storage :file
  elsif Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    if ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME'].to_s.include?('-pr-')
      "review_apps/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
    else
      "#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('test.jpg')
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :optimised do
    process convert: 'webp'
    process :set_content_type_to_webp

    def full_filename(_for_file = model.cover.file)
      "cover_#{model.id}.webp"
    end

    def exists?
      file&.exists?
    end
  end

  def extension_blacklist
    %w(webp)
  end

  private

  # Required to actually force Amazon S3 to treat it like an image
  def set_content_type_to_webp
    file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, 'image/webp')
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `recreate_versions!` command (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions) that Carrierwave provides?

Comment: I'd imagine it would work, but I was expecting `update` to do it for me. More importantly, it seems it gets called somehow, because after saving a new image, the old :optimised version is gone and all that remains is the standard, newly uploaded image. Which again, is not the behaviour I'd expect and I haven't seen this problem on another project that does similar things @AnujKhandelwal

Comment: please update a carrierwave's version

Comment: @ogelacinyc I have checked the changelog and since my version - 1.2.2, nothing has changed that could have affected this. I can try upgrading, as there is no harm in that, but was that just a random suggestion or you actually had something in mind?

Comment: @MaximFedotov Nope. There are some kind of misunderstaning. My comment was meaning to comment current your carrierwave version. I'm sorry for about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ogelacinyc was partly correct when he found the bug in `full_filename`. I went back to test normal functionality with creating another version, with a simple dimension change. I could then see that update would recreate the versions by itself, just like I expected.

That made me think that maybe there is something wrong with my `version :optimised` block. So after commenting one by one, I found that `full_filename` was the culprit. It could have been `model.cover.file` failing silently, but I think it was `model.id`, as can be seen in the description for [filename method in Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/a91ab69fdd8052cdf5a5e48ef8baf40939e441fb/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb#L22)

So instead, I grab the filename directly, extract extension and substitute it with webp:

```rb
  def full_filename(for_file = model.file_name.file)
    extension = File.extname(for_file)
    "cover_#{for_file.sub(extension, '.webp')}"
  end
```

Which works without problems!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `after_save` callback to Event and then call `recreate_versions!` on your mounted uploader.

Assuming you have an Event model with the following, this would solve your problem.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :cover_image, CoverUploader
  after_save :recreate_versions!
  delegate :recreate_versions!, to: :cover_image, allow_nil: true
end
```

See [CarrierWave's README](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions) also.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think this is needed and I'd like to avoid having to add a callback when it might not be needed. On a different project, I am part of, versions get recreated on the update, without anything additional added. And that's how I'd expect it to work...

Comment: The best advice I can give you then is to define a private method called `recreate_versions_if_needed!` then only call `cover_image.recreate_versions!` conditionally.  I just don't know enough about your specific apps requirements to advise what those conditions ought to be.

Comment: Sure, but do you need to? My question can be boiled down to: Does CarrierWave recreate versions automatically, on uploading a new image? My understanding that it does, hence trying to understand why it doesn't in my app. I am not doing anything out of ordinary, as far as I can tell. I would rather get to the bottom of the issue and fix it properly than put in a stopgap like adding this callback